# Forward output of a command line program into PHP script

Tags: php, windows, shell, command-line

I use a program (tshark) that capture real-time network data and show it on the screen. Is there any way to forward it into PHP (or other language script), thus every time new line (actually block of lines is added) my PHP script (parser) is called. Or I can call once parcer, but need to redirect output. How it is done?

Structure:
(tshark) [XML] => (parser PHP) => MySQL database.

Comment: Is it an option to call the program from php? Cause then you could use proc_open and read from the output and error stream fairly easily.

Comment: I am not familiar with tshark, but if it can output the data to a log file (text file) then you can read the logs using php and printing them...

Comment: Well, what about mutual file access (one write and one read) and what is more important - speed.

Comment: @towr, It is possible to call it form PHP. How output is read?

Comment: You mean to create pipe and read from it?

Comment: Yeah, with `proc_open` you can execute a command and open three pipes to it (input, output, error). Those are streams you can read from while the command continues running. If you use both output and error stream be sure to read from them alternately so one doesn't fill up and block things.